# Horn of Plenty not working

Tags: candy-box

I received Horn of Plenty from Cow Level and my production on the lollipop farm is 100 lp/sec. I planted almost 30000 lolipops. Why does it not work?

Answer (score 6):

It DOES work, the display shows you your base rate of lp/s, not the multiplied one.

If you watch your lollipop count, you'll see that it goes up by 300 every second.

Answer (score 6):

Without the Developper's computer, your lollipop production is limited to 100 a second.  The number of lollipops planted doesn't matter, that's the best you'll get.  The Horn of Plenty triples that, but doesn't alter the displayed production value.